# Regex to encapsulate any non-matched sections

Tags: c#, regex

Using the example phrase:

All men like **widgets** but some men like **widgets** more than others

The example contains two uses of the word *widgets*. What I'm trying to do is match the bits outside. Note that although widgets is one word, I'm looking for a regex solution that will also work with multiple words.

Given the above example, the output would contain 3 matches:

1. All men like
2. but some men like
3. more than others

So far, I have the following regex that only partly works:

```
@"(?!widgets\b)\b\w+"
```

The limitations are that it cannot cope with multiple words phrases - it also matches each negative word, rather than the whole string of words that precede /succeed, so "all", "men" and "like" rather than "all men like".

I have another solution which involves a simpler regex and some additional chopping and changing in c# code, but it's not a solution I'm happy with:

```
string EmboldenString(string text, string termToExclude)
{
    var pattern = $@" ?{termToExclude} ?";

    var tagStart = "<b>";
    var tagEnd = "</b>";

    var result = Regex.Replace($"{tagStart}{text}{tagEnd}", pattern, (match) =>
    {
        return $"{tagEnd}{match}{tagStart}";
    });

    var emptyTag = tagStart + tagEnd;

    if (result.StartsWith(emptyTag))
        result = result.TrimStart(emptyTag.ToCharArray());

    if (result.EndsWith(emptyTag))
        result = result.TrimEnd(emptyTag.ToCharArray());

    return result;
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the goal is to add tags to all the non-matching bits.

Anyone help with a better regex.

Comment: Use `Regex.Split()` instead. E.g., `\b(?:widgets|foo|bar)\b`.

Comment: In the code above, I add <b></b> tags around the matches but return the whole string - how is it possible to do this if I use  Regex.Split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Regex.Split` and then wrap each odd element in the resulting array/list with any tags you like:

```
var s = "All men like widgets but some men like widgets more than others";
var chunks = Regex.Split(s, @"(\s*\bwidgets\b\s*)");
var result = string.Concat(chunks.Select((i, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? $"<b>{i}</b>" : i));
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => <b>All men like</b> widgets <b>but some men like</b> widgets <b>more than others</b>
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/eUkPpA).

The `(\s*\bwidgets\b\s*)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 0+ whitespsaces, whole word `widgets` and again 0+ whitespaces. These matches are kept in the resulting array because they are captured. Each odd element is a non-matched substring.

If you do not want to wrap blank non-matches with tags add an extra `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i)` check:

```
var chunks = Regex.Split(s, @"(\s*\bwidgets\b\s*)");
var result = string.Concat(
    chunks.Select((i, index) => 
        index % 2 == 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i) ? 
            $"<b>{i}</b>" : i));
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/llY3gi).

Comment: Fantastic code Wiktor - but it doesn't work for all cases! If word 'widgets' is placed at the start or end, rather tan the middle, an extra set of empty tags is added.

Comment: @JohnOhara It is correct as is: there will be empty strings. When you render `<b></b>` the end user won't see any problem here. If you want, you may just remove all of them as a post-process step. `result = result.Replace("<b></b>", "");`

Comment: @JohnOhara Besides, you cannot write a regex not matching some arbitrary multicharacter string in .NET regex. Regex.Split is the simplest solution.

Comment: @JohnOhara Please also check https://ideone.com/llY3gi. It seems it may work as you need if you do not wrap empty/blank items with tags.

Comment: Thanks - that's great.

Answer (score 1):

As Ahmed suggested you should use `Regex.Spilt()`

Here is Example for your Use case

```
var op = Regex.Split("All men like widgets but some men like widgets more than others", @"widgets");
```

**Output**

```
//All men like
//but some men like
//more than others
```

**Update**

You can use below code

```
string op = GetTagsAroud("All men like widgets but some men like widgets more than others", @"widgets");
```

**Method**

```
static string GetTagsAroud(string input, string splitText)
{
    var matches = Regex.Split(input, splitText);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string match in matches)
    {
        output.Append("<b>");
        output.Append(match.Trim());
        output.Append("</b>");
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just trying to work out how to add <b></b> tags around the output. No delegate on Regex.Split and can't update the content of a ForEach.

Comment: So you want to add <b> tags around each string? 
like <b>All men like</b>
<b>but some men like</b> ?

Comment: That's correct, but I need to return the whole of the original string once amended: <b>All men like</b> widgets <b>but some men like</b> widgets <b>more than others</b>

Comment: Thanks for your input - didn't quite work though. Another answer now accepted but you might want to check your code for your own curiosity.