# Split string into words and rejoin with additional data

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have a method that uses `Regex` to find a pattern within a text `string`. It works, but isn't adequate going forward because it requires the text to appear in *the exact order*, rather than viewing the phrase as a set of words.

```
    public static string HighlightExceptV1(this string text, string wordsToExclude)
    {
        // Original version
        // wordsToExclude usually consists of a 1, 2 or 3 word term.
        // The text must be in a specific order to work.

        var pattern = $@"(\s*\b{wordsToExclude}\b\s*)";

        // Do something to string...
    }
```

This version improves upon the previous version, in that it does allow the words to be matched in any order, but it *causes some spacing issues* in the final output because the spacing is removed and replaced with the pipes.

```
    public static string HighlightExceptV2(this string text, string wordsToExclude)
    {
        // This version allows the words to be matched in any order, but it has
        // flaws, in that the natural spacing is removed in some cases.
        var words = wordsToExclude.Replace(' ', '|');

        var pattern = $@"(\s*\b{words}\b\s*)";

        // Example phase: big blue widget
        // Example output: $@"(\s*\bbig|blue|widget\b\s*)"

        // Do something to string...
    }
```

Ideally, the spacing needs to be preserved around each word. The pseudo example below shows what I'm trying to do.

1. split the original phrase into words
2. wrap each word within a regex pattern that will preserve the space
   when matched
3. rejoin the word patterns to produce the pattern that will be used to
   match

   ```
   public static string HighlightExceptV3(this string text, string wordsToExclude)
   {
       // The outputted pattern must be dynamic due to unknown
       // words in phrase.

       // Example phrase: big blue widgets

       var words = wordsToExclude.Replace(' ', '|');
       // Example: big|blue|widget

       // The code below isn't complete - merely an example
       // of the required output.

       var wordPattern = $@"\s*\b{word}\b\s*";
       // Example: $@"\s*\bwidget\b\s*"

       var phrasePattern = "$({rejoinedArray})";
       // @"(\s*\bbig\b\s*|\s*\bblue\b\s*|\s*\bwidget\b\s*)";

       // Do something to string...
   }
   ```

Note: There could be better ways of dealing with the word boundaries spacing but I'm not a regex expert.

**I'm looking for some help/advice to take the split array, wrap it , then rejoin it in the neatest way.**

Comment: Maybe - if you have 1 space separated words that only consist of word chars - just use `var phrasePattern = $@"\s*\b(?:{wordsToExclude.Replace(" ", "|")})\b\s*";`

Comment: What is the original problem, please? Suppose, you are given a phrase, e.g. `"The quick brown fox (not wolf or cat) runs, jumps over a lazy (!) dog."` and *words to exclude*, e.g. `{"wolf", "over", "the"}`. What is the desired outcome then?

Comment: As I said, I'm not a regex expert, but the code below just seems like a variation of the V2 example - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnOhara My suggested piece of code in the top comment is a **fix** of your V2 example.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - here's an example for big blue widgets, "big widgets are great but better if blue" - the output will eventually have html appended using regex "blue widgets <b>are great but better</b> big"

Comment: So it is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55794603/3832970? Then use `var phrasePattern = $@"(\s*\b(?:{wordsToExclude.Replace(" ", "|")})\b\s*)"` - unless you may have special chars inside the "words". Then you need  `var phrasePattern = $@"(\s*\b(?:{string.Join("|", wordsToExclude.Split(' ').Select(Regex.Escape))})\b\s*)"`. Or even more tweaks are necessary if the special chars can be at the start/end of the "words" (`\b...\b` = > `(?<!\w)... (?!\w)`)

Comment: So does `var phrasePattern = $@"(\s*(?<!\w)(?:{string.Join("|", wordsToExclude.Split(' ').Select(Regex.Escape))})(?!\w)\s*)";` do the job? It is the best way if you have one space separated words in the `wordsToExclude` and you have no idea what chars there might be

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes, the requirement has been changed. I've just been testing your suggestion but it breaks the original solution - only the wordsToExclude are returned.

Comment: Please share the code fiddle.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - fiddle: https://ideone.com/EycC9m

Comment: See https://ideone.com/uyQ18s, I  get `<b>there are</b> big widgets <b>in this phrase</b> blue widgets <b>too</b>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I don't know how you work these regex's out, but I'm glad you do - works superb. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose all your alternatives within a non-capturing group, `(?:...|...)`. Besides, to further counter eventual issues, I suggest replacing word boundaries with their lookaround unambiguous equivalents, `(?<!\w)...(?!\w)`.

Here is a [working C# snippet](https://ideone.com/uyQ18s):

```
var text = "there are big widgets in this phrase blue widgets too";
var words = "big blue widgets";
var pattern = $@"(\s*(?<!\w)(?:{string.Join("|", words.Split(' ').Select(Regex.Escape))})(?!\w)\s*)";
var result = string.Concat(Regex.Split(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Select((str, index) =>
            index % 2 == 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? $"<b>{str}</b>" : str));
 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**NOTES**

- `words.Split(' ').Select(Regex.Escape)` - splits the `words` text with spaces and regex-escapes each item
- `string.Join("|",...)` re-builds the string inserting `|` between the items
- `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a word char, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with a word char.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing *FSM* (Finite State Machine) with `2` states (in and out selection) and `Regex.Replace` (we can keep the word as it is - `word` or replace it with `<b>word`, `word<\b>` or `<b>word<\b>`)

```
private static string MyModify(string text, string wordsToExclude) {
  HashSet<string> exclude = new HashSet<string>(
    wordsToExclude.Split(' '), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  bool inSelection = false;

  string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\w']+", match => {
      var next = match.NextMatch();

      if (inSelection) {
        if (next.Success && exclude.Contains(next.Value)) {
          inSelection = false;

          return match.Value + "</b>";
        }
        else
          return match.Value;
      }
      else {
        if (exclude.Contains(match.Value))
          return match.Value;
        else if (next.Success && exclude.Contains(next.Value))
          return "<b>" + match.Value + "</b>";
        else {
          inSelection = true;
          return "<b>" + match.Value;
        }
      }
    });

  if (inSelection)
    result += "</b>";

  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string wordsToExclude = "big widgets blue if";

string[] tests = new string[] {
  "widgets for big blue",
  "big widgets are great but better if blue",
  "blue",
  "great but expensive",
  "big and small, blue and green",
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,-40} -> {MyModify(test, wordsToExclude)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
widgets for big blue                     -> widgets <b>for</b> big blue
big widgets are great but better if blue -> big widgets <b>are great but better</b> if blue
blue                                     -> blue
great but expensive                      -> <b>great but expensive</b>
big and small, blue and green            -> big <b>and small</b>, blue <b>and green</b>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution Dmitry.

Comment: Dmitry, this is such a  great solution (I learnt something new today), that I've taken some time to try and understand it. I've done quite a bit of testing, but noticed it fails in one scenario - want to take a look? https://ideone.com/RIQW2x

Comment: Dmitry, you've highlighted the error. "widgets <b>for big</b> blue" - the <b> section includes one of our reserved words - "big". It should output "widgets <b>for</b> big blue"

Comment: @John Ohara: Nice catch! `<b>SingleWord</b>` has not been covered. I've edited the answer

Comment: Dmitry, code has passed all previous fails - so it looks like it's now good. Thanks again.