# How to get groups names using Regex.Split

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on strings that **may** contain things between parenthesis, such as :

```
"Hello World"
"(Hello) World"
"(Hello World)"
"(Hello) (World)"
"bla bla (Hello World) bla bla"
"Hello (World"
```

I wrote this simple regex for that purpose : `\((.*?)\)` :

```
var Inputs = new List<string>
{
    "Hello World",
    "(Hello) World",
    "(Hello World)",
    "(Hello) (World)",
    "bla bla (Hello World) bla bla",
    "Hello (World"
};

foreach (var input in Inputs)
{
    var parts = Regex.Split(input, @"\((.*?)\)");

    Console.WriteLine($"Input : {input}");
    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"> '{part}'");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
}
```

This is giving me the **expected** Outputs :

```
Input : Hello World
> 'Hello World'
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello) World
> ''
> 'Hello'
> ' World'
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello World)
> ''
> 'Hello World'
> ''
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello) (World)
> ''
> 'Hello'
> ' '
> 'World'
> ''
--------------------------------
Input : bla bla (Hello World) bla bla
> 'bla bla '
> 'Hello World'
> ' bla bla'
--------------------------------
Input : Hello (World
> 'Hello (World'
--------------------------------
```

However I need a special treatment for the captured parts between parenthesis.

I thought using named groups, such as `(?<others1>.*?)\((?<choice>.*?)\)(?<others2>.*?)`, but working with groups requier to use methods such as `Match()` and `GetGroupNames()` and I'm getting wrong results :

```
// Inputs are the same than above
foreach (var input in Inputs)
{        
    var rgx = new Regex(@"(?<others1>.*?)\((?<choice>.*?)\)(?<others2>.*?)");

    var matches = rgx.Matches(input);
    var groups = rgx.GetGroupNames();


    Console.WriteLine($"Input : {input}");
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Group grp = match.Groups[group];
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}: '{1}'", group, grp.Value);
            // if (group == "choice")
            //     SpecialTreatment(grp.Value);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
}
```

Output :

```
Input : Hello World // no match
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello) World // Missing ' World'
   0: '(Hello)'
   others1: ''
   choice: 'Hello'
   others2: ''
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello World) // Good
   0: '(Hello World)'
   others1: ''
   choice: 'Hello World'
   others2: ''
--------------------------------
Input : (Hello) (World) // Good
   0: '(Hello)'
   others1: ''
   choice: 'Hello'
   others2: ''
   0: ' (World)'
   others1: ' '
   choice: 'World'
   others2: ''
--------------------------------
Input : bla bla (Hello World) bla bla // missing last part ' bla bla'
   0: 'bla bla (Hello World)'
   others1: 'bla bla '
   choice: 'Hello World'
   others2: ''
--------------------------------
Input : Hello (World // no match
--------------------------------
```

Is there a way to benefit the group names with `Regex.Split()` ?

Comment: `.*?` at the end of the pattern never matches any char. Why do you need named groups? You do not need them, this is an XY problem. Please explain what you need to achieve in the end.  So, you have `bla bla (Hello World) bla bla`, what do you need to get in the end?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just figured out why `.*?` is useless at the end, this is lazy match and *empty string* will match. I need to apply a `String.Split()` and then some computation on the `(...)` matches only, that's why I thought using names could help me to identify thoses parts

Comment: For `bla bla (Hello World) bla bla`, I need to retrieve the parts before, after and inside the `()`

Comment: So, your code works. Why change it? Why ask a question?

Comment: Because I can't tell which part was between parenthesis

Comment: You can. What do you need to do with the part between parentheses?

Comment: Please explain what you are doing, or you are going to have many more irrelevant answers copying your question.

Comment: as input, I can have something like `xxx (abc|def|ghi) yyy (ijk|lmn|opq) zzz`, final output should be `xxx abc yyy lmn zzz`. Every time I'm getting parenthesis, I need to `Split('|')` and get the index `i % SplitLength` item, then, apply an `i++`. I can have `(rst)` aswell, and I need to figure out that I need to apply the `i++`. I hope it's clear

Comment: See https://ideone.com/MPLG2D. Something like `string.Concat(Regex.Split(text, pattern).Select((str, index) =>
                index % 2 == 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? str : str.Split('|').FirstOrDefault()));` might work.

Comment: Thank you for your time @WiktorStribiżew, but I actually need to go away. I will study and tweak your suggestion

Comment: Just let me know if it helps, I will post. Let me know if it does not and what does not work, I will fix.

Comment: Do you need https://ideone.com/MgxQRX?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you want more details, my problem comes from [Coding Game](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/bulk-email-generator). I think I will `Regex.Split()` using this one `(\(.*?\))` to keep the parenthesis and then write a method that checks if `str[0] == '(' && str[len - 1] == ')'`

Comment: Have a look at https://ideone.com/QVqgjg. It seems to work in the online IDE, but produces strange output in the CG console. You do not need that strange check as `if (j % 2 == 0)` already does it. All odd items are outside parentheses and all even ones are inside.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I finally solved my problem by keeping the parenthesis in the capture and writting a method returning `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) && str[0] == '(' && str[str.Length - 1] == ')';`. I think I will delete this question since it became specific to a particular problem instead of being something general as stated the title *"How to get groups names using Regex.Split"*. Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, this question has been misunderstood by many. Also, you do not really need that check you described, you can use my approach. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037857/split-string-into-words-and-rejoin-with-additional-data/56038904#56038904) that is almost a dupe reason for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this question is all over the map. Do you want the end result or do you want a fix to one step in the process? Part being a programmer is breaking things down into small steps and working on each step. You haven't done that...so lets do that:

1. Match either non grouped text or grouped text.
2. If it is grouped then separate out each individual item into a list.
3. If its non-grouped, then take it as is.
4. When recombining if it is a grouped scenario take the item in the list which +1 indexed than the last operation.

So which do you have an issue with? When asking a SO question, just keep it to a small bite size chunk.

---

Looking at the [bulk-email-generator problem](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/bulk-email-generator), the answer to that question can be done using regex, but one has to use the capture groups found within a match to properly separate the items out. Once they are separated, then you can take the target item which is an index that increases after each match.

**Example**

```
xxx (abc|def|ghi) yyy (ijk|lmn|opq) zzz
```

**End Result**

```
 xxx abc yyy lmn zzz
```

**Pattern**
Here is the pattern, commented for explanation. This regex finds groups **OR** non groups. From within the groups, it adds the separate text to an internal capture array :

```
var pattern = @"          # Either its in a Group
 \(                            #(literal paren start)
     (
       (?<Grouped>[^|(]+)      # Match up to the pipe or paren
       \|?                     # Don't match the pipe but consume it if there
    )+                         # One to many of these piped items
 \)                               # (literal paren stop)
|                          # Or its not in a group
 (?<NotGrouped>[^(]+)          #
";
```

Note we will tell regex parser to use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` (allows us to comment the pattern **before** regex parsing and also `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` which lets the regex parser ignore anything not within a named match capture `(?<NameHere> )`.

**Regex Result**

```
Match #0
                   [0]:  xxx
     ["Grouped"] → [1]:
  ["NotGrouped"] → [2]:  xxx
           →2 Captures: xxx
Match #1
                   [0]:  (abc | def | ghi)
     ["Grouped"] → [1]:  ghi
           →1 Captures: abc, def, ghi
 ["NotGrouped"] → [2]:
Match #2
                   [0]:   yyy
     ["Grouped"] → [1]:
  ["NotGrouped"] → [2]:   yyy
           →2 Captures: yyy
Match #3
                   [0]:  (ijk | lmn | opq)
     ["Grouped"] → [1]:  opq
           →1 Captures: ijk, lmn, opq
 ["NotGrouped"] → [2]:
Match #4
                   [0]:   zzz
     ["Grouped"] → [1]:
  ["NotGrouped"] → [2]:   zzz
           →2 Captures: zzz
```

So if the grouping is `NonPiped` we ignore the Captures (for there is only one) an stick with the match itself. If it is one of the data groups, we focus on the `Captures`.

**C# Solution**

```
int index = 0;

string.Join(string.Empty,

Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mtch => mtch.Groups["NotGrouped"].Success ? mtch.Groups["NotGrouped"].Value
                                                       : mtch.Groups["Grouped"].Captures
                                                                               .OfType<Capture>()
                                                                               .Select(cpt => cpt.Value)
                                                                               .ToList()[index++]
             )

    )
```

Result is `xxx abc yyy lmn zzz`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a slightly different regex that keeps the brackets:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(input, @"(\(.*?\))");
```

One of the example in the question should then report:

```
Input : (Hello) World
> ''
> '(Hello)'
> ' World'
```

It is then a simple matter of checking the first and last characters of each element of `parts` for brackets.

---

Another approach would use:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(input, @"([()])");
```

This should yield:

```
Input : (Hello) World
> ''
> '('
> 'Hello'
> ')'
> ' World'
```

This also shows the bracketed text clearly.